# How to reinstall Elixir properly？

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I use `brew remove elixir --force` and `brew install elixir`.
`elixir -v` shows

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.2
```

Then I use `mix local.hex`. `mix hex.info` shows

```
Hex:    0.13.0
Elixir: 1.3.2
OTP:    19.0.2

Built with: Elixir 1.3.2 and OTP 18.3.4.2
```

Finally, I start a new phoenix project. But the mix.exs shows

```
def project do
  [app: :b,
   version: "0.0.1",
   elixir: "~> 1.2",
   elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
   compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
   build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
   start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
   aliases: aliases(),
   deps: deps()]
 end
```

Why, the mix.exs file shows the wrong version of Elixir, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is ok with your Elixir version. When you generate Elixir app with `mix new my_app` it will have by default `1.3` version, however only Phoenix projects [still use `1.2`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/installer/lib/phoenix_new.ex).

Comment: I test again find "Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] y
* running mix deps.get
* running npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build"  This  part is not working.